# In Angular 14, how do I reference nested child elements in the definition of a parent element?

Tags: angular, nested, angular-components, angular14

I'm using Angular 14.  I want to construct custom components such that a parent tag can have nested child elements.  So for example, I'd like to have

```
<app-my-parent>
    <p>Hello</p>
</app-my-parent>
```

but I'd also like to have

```
<app-my-parent>
    <app-my-child></app-my-child>
</app-myparent>
```

BUt i'm unsure how to create the "my-parent" component such that I can display the content of what is nested.  In the definition of my-parent.copmonent.html, I'd like to have something like

```
<div>Howdy, these are the nested contents</div>
<div>{{ nestedContents }}</div>
And here they are again!
<div>{{ nestedContents }}</div>
```

but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: You might want to take a look into Content Projection, see https://angular.io/guide/content-projection

Comment: <ng-content> should help you. Here is a video tutorial which I find helpful. Google some more about content projection and ng-content specifically. link: https://angular-university.io/lesson/angular-content-projection